# two jquery functions at the same time

Tags: jquery, function, click, bind, each

I'm having two jquery's that I run and I want to combine them both in the same line. 
Here's an example of what i'm trying to do.

```
    ​$(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $(this).after('this is checked');
        }
    });
    $('input').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $(this).after('this is checked');
        }
    });
});​
```

Now, both functions do the same thing, one is executed for checking if there are any inputs being checked from the backend, the other one just responds to user clicks.

I was thinking if i can combine them in a statement like this,

```
$('input').bind('each click');
```

but i noticed that even this wouldn't work with each. 
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just name the function..

```
function handler() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $(this).after('this is checked');
    }
}
```

then use it in both situations:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').each(handler);
    $('input').click(handler);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind the `each` method, because it's not an event.

Assign the function to a variable, so that you can reuse it:

```
​$(function(){

  var markChecked = function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $(this).after('this is checked');
    }
  };

  $('input').each(markChecked).click(markChecked);
});​
```

Another approach that is used sometimes is to trigger a click event on each element to force the initial check:

```
​$(function(){
  $('input').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $(this).after('this is checked');
    }
  }).click();
});​
```

This of course assumes that triggering the click event doesn't have any side effects. If you already have bound another click event handler to any of the elements, this would cause that event handler to be called also.